# Cannot update the value inside an object that is part of a node in a list

Tags: c++, pointers, object, linked-list

I have a basic linked list with an object. The rough structure is something like this:

```
class Something {
  public:
    Something();
    ~Something();
    void setValue(int v);

  private:
    int value;
}


class Node {
  public:
    Node();
    ~Node();
    Node* getNext();
    Something getSome();

  private:
    Something some;
    Node *next;
}


class List {
  public:
    List();
    ~List();
    void updateValues(int v);

  private:
    Node* first;
    Node* current;
}
```

Then, on the method `updateValues()` I want to change the values of the `Something` of a given `Node`. But the values are not changed. The remain the same as before. I'm trying something like this:

```
void List::updateValues(int v) {
  Node* iterator = first;

  while(it != NULL) {
    it->getSome()->setValue(v);
    it = it->getNext();
  }
}
```

However, the `value` of each `Something` on each `Node` is not changed. I'm aware that this is an issue of pointers and references, but I'm not fully understanding how to fix it.

Comment: `getSome()` returns a *copy* - change the function signature to `Something& getSome();`

Comment: @PaulSanders because this is a school assignment. The assignment implied coding our own list to learn their inner working mechanics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getSome()` method returns a *copy* of the stored `Something`. Your code modifies only this copy. This can be fixed by returning and working on a *reference* instead:

```
  Something& getSome();
```